# javascript retrieve date like the users local date in windows tray

Tags: javascript, datetime, localization

i have an input on my webapp like this:

var t = '2012-03-27T23:30:00Z';

What i want is to change the above to the users local date format like in the windows local tray (e.g: 28.3.2012.)

When i have this, i want to add a short day of week in front of it (localized). So generally this is the desired result:

Wed, 28.3.2012. 10:10

ps.

Side question: Why does javascript's toLocaleDateString(); give different results in firefox and safari?

firefox -> my local language
safari -> english

If i knew how to retrieve the current local users date format, e.g. mm/dd/yy VS dd/mm/yy

This could help, then i would just need to retrieve the current local day of week (which can be ectracted from: toDateString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your suggested approach is that you can't control what will be displayed when using `toLocaleDateString()`. For example, on my machine in Chome the following code

```
var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var d = new Date();
var str = days[d.getDay()] + ', ' + d.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + d.toLocaleTimeString();
```

would output

```
"Wed, Wednesday, March 28, 2012 01:30:00"
```

My suggestion would be to use a framework for culture specific formatting, for example [jQuery Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize), and append weekday to the culture specific short date format pattern.

The answer to your question about why you get different output i Firefox is actually the same as above; toLocalDateString()'s format depends on platform, locale and user's settings. Se [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) for more information.